# Rails Capistrano App - Environment Variables getting changed in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, capistrano, passenger

**Tech Stack** :
Rails, Capistrano and Phusion Passenger App with Nginx, Ubuntu 14.04

The `ENV['PATH']` variable is showing different values when querying it through Rails Console and when application is running.

e.g. In Rails Console, the value is:  `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin`
While when running application, it is showing : `/usr/local/ruby/1.9.1/bin`

This is causing OS level operations to fail while running application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by explicitly setting the PATH variable in nginx configuration, using the `passenger_env_var` attribute.

I am still not sure why the PATH variable was being reset by Passenger/Nginx, but this workaround seemed to work.